# How do I get a Digital Personal U 4500 fingerprint scanner working?

Tags: drivers, fingerprint-reader

I have an external USB-based fingerprint scanner. On MS Windows it is used to save fingerprints as images. Are there any drivers and softwares to get it working on Ubuntu?

Edit:
The device I use is "Digital Persona U are U 4500"

Comment: Can you tell us which fingerprint scanner you have? One way to do this is to edit your post to include the output of `lsusb`.

Comment: Also, have you tried using Simple Scan? This is accessible from Applications->Graphics->Simple Scan.

Answer (score 3):

## [Fprint](http://www.reactivated.net/fprint/wiki/Main_Page) [image: install fprint-demo]

Fprint is a project to support fingerprint readers in Linux. You can install [fprint-demo](http://packages.ubuntu.com/fprint-demo) from the Software Centre to get a graphical application that may be able
to do what you want.

You should check against the [supported](http://www.reactivated.net/fprint/wiki/Supported_devices) and [unsupported](http://www.reactivated.net/fprint/wiki/Unsupported_devices) devices to see if your reader will work.

Comment: I couldn't see an easy way to use the fingerprint scanner as an authentication method, however.  Although I believe that Fedora are leading the way there and recently System76 have released some Ubuntu-based laptops with fprint enabled authentication.

Comment: That was not asked in the question. You could ask this as a separate question though.

Comment: The devise I use is "Digital Persona U are U 4500". It is there in the supported list. The software detects the device, but it doesn't scan. I continually waits. The divice LED's doesn't lit up.

Comment: Screenshot is dead. Do you have another?